# What are some good logic simulators for experimenting with multiplexers?

Tags: simulation, logic-gates, multiplexer

We've been tasked with showing the numbers on a 7-segment led display with dual 4x1 multiplexers and 3 variables. Our first try was a failure and we won't have the opportunity to experiment in the next few days, is there any good program for this kind of project? I've tried logisim but the cable on the selection variables(I don't know if this is the name in english) is always orange .-.

Comment: Try Logisim....

Comment: Just FYI, support for Logisim ended years ago.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Well.. it's functional and pretty good as it is :)

Comment: I've tried using logisim but there was that problem I mentioned in the question that I don't know how to solve as I'm quite new with all of this. If you don't mind explaining it, it would be very appreciated!

Comment: @MartinhoTavares Orange means the cable has several separate wires in it and you tried to connect two cables with different numbers of wires. Use a splitter to separate out the wires.

Answer (score 1):

You could try SmartSim,  I've not actually used it but it is worth a try:

https://smartsim.org.uk/

It is is currently available to download for Windows and Linux computers